Why can't the GET handler function be reached with the new advanced routing in go 1.22?
I'm playing around with the new go 1.22 features, but I can't seem to reach GET "/users/register" handler function and instead receive 404. What is the issue here?
snippet from package main:
func main() {
    if err := godotenv.Load(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to load .env:", err)
    }

    _, err := repository.InitDB()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to initialise the database:", err)
    }

    userMux := http.NewServeMux()
    if err := handlers.InitUserRoutes(userMux); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to initialise user routes:", err)
    }

    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.Handle("/users/", userMux)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", os.Getenv("DOMAIN"), os.Getenv("PORT")), mux))
}

snippet from package handlers:
var templates *template.Template

func InitUserRoutes(mux *http.ServeMux) error {
    var err error
    templates, err = utils.ParseTemplates("web/templates/user")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    mux.HandleFunc("GET /register/", registerGet)
    mux.HandleFunc("POST /register/", registerPost)

    return nil
}

func registerGet(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("I'm here")
    err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "register.html", nil)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}

func registerPost(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n\n%#v", r.Form, r.PostForm)
    email, username, password := r.FormValue("email"), r.FormValue("username"), r.FormValue("password")
    fmt.Printf("%v, %v, %v\n", email, username, password)
}

snippet from package utils:
func ParseTemplates(folderPath string) (*template.Template, error) {
    return template.ParseGlob(filepath.Join(folderPath, "*.html"))
}


@BurakSerdar tried already, it doesn't work.

You have to handle GET /users/register/ or use http.StripPrefix in main.

@Peter It seems for the first idea to work, I would have to go with the mainMux instead and not intialise a userMux. So that leaves the second idea, and it has to be that way because if you don't strip the prefix, it leaves the pattern looking as follows:
"/users/GET /register/".
So, the line should look like so:
mux.Handle("/users/", http.StripPrefix("/users", userMux))
Am I correct to understand this?
EDIT: also the trailing slash seems to be mandatory because without it, you get redirected to "/register/" from "/users/register" for some reason. Which I don't quite understand.

it works fine for me
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    prefix := "/users"
    userMux := http.NewServeMux()
    userMux.HandleFunc("GET /register/", registerGet)
    userMux.HandleFunc("GET /register2/", registerGet)
    userMux.HandleFunc("POST /register/", registerPost)

    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.Handle("/users/{pathname...}", http.StripPrefix(prefix, userMux))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":12345", mux))
}

func registerGet(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, r.Method, "I'm here", r.RequestURI)
}

func registerPost(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, r.Method, "I'm here", r.RequestURI)
}



TLDR: make sure to update the go version in go.mod
I updated my old project with the new routing patterns and the endpoints started to return 404. After debugging, the httpmuxgo121 godebug option was somehow set to 1. After setting env GODEBUG=httpmuxgo121=0, the HTTP paths started working.
There's an order in which godebug loads the settings. From https://go.dev/doc/godebug
its value is derived from three sources: the defaults for the Go toolchain used to build the program, amended to match the Go version listed in go.mod, and then overridden by explicit //go:debug lines in the program.

I wanted to specify the setting in go.mod and realized I completely forgot to update the go version in there! The setting httpmuxgo121 was amended to be compatible with my old go version! After changing it to 1.23, the path patterns started working!
